# Опечатка в блоке закрытия вопроса

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, закрытие-вопросов

Когда вопрос помечается как требующий правки (закрыт), в тексте пометки опечатка: "объявлен (время) требущим правки пользователем", т.е. пропущена буква Ю. Правильно "объявлен (время) требующим правки пользователем".

Также имеет смысл заменить слово "пользователем" на "пользователями", если голосов о закрытии вопроса было больше одного. Т.е. если модератор закрыл, писать "пользователем", если пять человек, или хотя бы один плюс модератор, то "пользователями".

Comment: Вопросы ещё могут закрывать в одиночку пользователи с золотым знаком по метке из вопроса.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По поводу пропущенной «Ю», я виноват и уже исправил.

По поводу «пользователем/пользователями» — в транзифексе есть только одна форма для английского `**put on hold** as $closeReason$ by $userCommas$ $onDate$`. Нужно потребовать разные формы.

---

С некоторого времени в Transifex [есть три формы для разного числа пользователей](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/51941568?q=**put%20on%20hold**%20as%20%24closeReason%24%20by%20%24userCommas%24%20%24onDate%24). Так что проблема полностью решена.

Comment: тогда, вероятно, лучше остановиться на множественном числе. ведь их (проголосовавших пользователей) чаще больше одного (насколько я знаю и вижу).

Comment: Думал как сделать без добавления дополнительных строк, так и не придумал. Попросил ребят, чтобы добавили три формы. Отпишусь, как исправим!

Comment: Выборка ([1](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40265895?q=userComm), [2](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40265905?q=usersComm)) всех подобных строк.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: Спасибо!

Comment: @VladD Ребята добавили строки, я их перевел. Ждем обновления сборки движка!